# Why does a wound-rotor induction motor produce a higher starting torque?

Tags: motor, induction-motor

I know that with a wound-rotor we can add external resistance and in this way reduce starting current but doesn't a lower current mean a lower torque?

I'm guessing that an additional resistance causes more things to happen and that's why the torque is greate, for example a smaller counter-emf.

Comment: Are you referring at induction motor with wound rotor and slip rings? If yes, then you should look at torque/speed characteristics of an induction motor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a wound rotor motor, increasing the rotor resistance doesn't change the maximum torque, but it causes the slip to increase reducing the speed at which the peak torque occurs. At a certain added resistance, the peak torque is reduced to zero speed.

Counter emf is not generally not used in induction motor modeling and analysis. The mechanism by which electrical energy is converted to mechanical energy is modeled by a variable resistance in series with the rotor resistance.